# Read param in symfony from plain php class

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I have a plain PHP class and I want to read one of the parameter from config.yml file. I dont have a container instance to read and get the param value. How can I achieve this in a plain PHP class? Important thing is that I can not make a service of my php class.

Comment: what is the question exactly, can you add an example, it is not clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually very easy, since `YAML` is component on it's own:

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;

$yaml = new Parser();

try {
    $yamlData = $yaml->parse(file_get_contents('/path/to/config.yml'));

    // adjust what you need to read here.
    $paramValue = $yamlData['your_key']['sub_key'];

} catch (ParseException $e) {
    printf("Unable to parse the YAML string: %s", $e->getMessage());
}
```

**Source: [Reading YAML Files](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/introduction.html#reading-yaml-files)**